# javax.validation.constraints for primitive boolean?

Tags: java, boolean

Small question on javax.validation.constraints and how to validate the **primitive** boolean (not Boolean)

Currently, I am using @Min(1),  @Size(min = 1, max = 10), @NotBlank, etc, to validate my primitive int, and String object. It is doing the job fine, very happy.

How to validate the same for a primitive boolean please?
Meaning, I have a boolean that I would like to be a **must** input in the JSON request.

I understand if I do Boolean, I can combine it wit some kind of @NotNull validation. How to do the same with the primitive boolean please?

I would like the client to must input this field. And the value of the field must be either true or false.

I do not want to default it to false or true if the field is not present.

This is a valid example

```
{
    "field": false
}
```

Here, there is a typo in the field, hence, the field field is not present, it is not valid.

```
{
    "fielddwdw": false
}
```

Here, the value of the field is "true", the string, hence invalid.

```
{
    "field": "true"
}
```

Here, the value is neither true or false, invalid

```
{
    "field": foo
}
```

I was hoping for some kind of

```
    @MagicalBooleanValidationAnnoation
    private boolean field;
```

But just would like to achieve this use case.

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do the same as a `Boolean` with `@NotNull` annotation for a *primitive* `boolean`, because the *primitive* `boolean` has only 2 possible values, and none of them represent the lack of a value.

If you want a 3-state value, with states `true`, `false`, and `missing`, you must use `Boolean`.

Or you can use an `enum` with 3 values.